# $T$ is a transformation that sets $T^2=-I$, is it necessarily unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthonormal

I need help in an argument over the following question.

> Let $V$ be a unitary space and let $T:V\rightarrow V$ a linear transformation that
>   sets $T^2=-I$, is $T$ necessarily a unitary transformation?

We had this question in an exam, and the official answer is:

> Since $(T-iI)(T+iI)=0$, the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides the
>   polynomial $(x-i)(x+i)$, hence $T$ must be diagonalizable, so there is a
>   basis $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ such that
>   $[T]_B=\operatorname{diag}(i,i,i,\ldots,-i,-i,-i)$. So
>   $[T]_B^*=\operatorname{diag}(-i,-i,-i,\ldots,i,i,i)$ hence
>   $[T]_B[T]_B^*=\operatorname{diag}(-i^2,-i^2,-i^2,\ldots,-i^2,-i^2,-i^2)=I$, so $T$ is
>   unitary.

But $[T^*]_B=[T]_B^*$ iff $B$ is an orthonormal basis, so something is missing in the proof, am I right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement is false. Take $T(x,y)=(x-y,2x-y)$. Then $T^2(x,y)=(-x,-y)$, but $T$ is *not* unitary.

And, yes, what you wrote about the fact that the basis needs to be orthogonal in order to reach the desired conclusion is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The argument is proving that $T$ is unitary with respect to *some* positive definite Hermitian inner product on $V$, not that it is unitary with respect to a pre-existing choice.

More generally, any finite-order automorphism of $V$ is unitary with respect to some choice of positive definite Hermitian inner product structure on $V$ (by essentially the argument that proves Maschke's theorem).

Comment: I disagree. We are talking about an  [unitary space](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Unitary_space). Therefore, the inner product is given from the start.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I agree that the inner product is given from the start, and therefore the statement as claimed is false! The argument in the question does, however, prove something. Namely, it proves that $T$ is unitary with respect to a (possibly different) inner product. That's all. What is your disagreement, exactly?

Comment: By that argument, “unitary” and “diagonalizable” would mean the same thing.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No, by that argument "unitary with respect to some inner product" and "diagonalizable with eigenvalues of absolute value one" mean the same thing. Which, in fact, they do.

Comment: This is false. Take $f\colon\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ defined by $f(z)=2z$. It not diagonalizable with eigenvalues of absolute value one, but, nevertheless, it is unitary with respect to some inner product.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No, it is not.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ...$f$ unitary with respect to $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $v$ and eigenvector of $f$ of eigenvalue $e$ implies $(v,v)=(f(v),f(v))=(ev,ev)=e \overline{e} (v,v)=|e|^2 (v,v)$. Now, where is your confusion?